# Getting Django to play nice with Angular routing

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have an existing Django project and am adding a new app which consists of an API (using the rest-framework) and an angular app. This app contains one Django template, which simply serves as a way for Angular to hook in, and then work with it's own partials:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div ui-view></div>

{% endblock %}
```

From here, I would like for angular to take over the routing of the application:

```
$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;

// Routing
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

$stateProvider
    .state('list', {
        url: '/routines',
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/routine/routine_list.html',
        controller: 'RoutineListController',
    })
    .state('add', {
        url: '/routines/add',
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/routine/routine_add_edit.html',
        controller: 'RoutineAddController',
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/routines');
```

This works fine for the first page the app loads, however attempting to navigate to any subsequent page results in Django displaying a 404 error message

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/routines/add
```

Based on my current (limited) knowledge of both systems, I attempted to specify a url in my Django config that would apply to all routine/* urls and not load a template, allowing angular to request the partial it requires so it can continue running the SPA uninterrupted. However, I was unable to find any information on specifying a URL without a template, leading me to believe that this is not the correct solution.

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.routineView, name='routine'),

url(r'^/.*$', views.routineView, name='angular'),
```

Summary:
I would like to use Angular and a Django rest API app to create a web application. However, I would like to keep the rest of my existing Django site and simply add this on (an embedded SPA in my current Django base.html template). How do I set up the routing (on both Angular and Django) so that Django allows Angular to run interrupted once a certain page has been requested (in this case site.com/routines).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you simply want to use AngularJS with Django Rest API along with Django templates for some routes. I did this before using this https://github.com/mgonto/restangular. All you need to create a service that represent the resource. Here is a sample code for the service in AngularJS:

```
(function() {
    function Course(Restangular) {
        var service = Restangular.all("course");
        //studentStats refers to the corresponding JS function that will call the API (note API URL is configured in app.js)
        //student_stats refers to the corresponding url in Django API
        service.addRestangularMethod("studentStats", "get", "student_statuses");
        return service;
    }
    angular.module("YOUR-APP")
    .service("Course", ["Restangular", Course]);
}).call(null);
```